# Roblox Studio: Shop System

Tags: roblox

**Hello,**

I have a shop system that half works. It has one problem. When you buy something from the shop, your money goes down, as it's suppose to. But then if you get more money, the number of your money springs back up to what it was, plus it gives you the new money that you got. I don't know how to fix it. This is the code.

```
local price = script.Parent.Parent.Price
local tools = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Tools")
local tool = script.Parent.Parent.ItemName
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Money").Value >= price.Value then 
        player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Money").Value = player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Money").Value - price.Value
        game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy:FireServer(tool.Value)
    end
end)
```

This is the code that puts the item in the inventory:

```
local tools = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Tools")

game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,tool)
    
    local clone = tools:FindFirstChild(tool):Clone()
    clone.Parent = player.Backpack

    local clone2 = tools:FindFirstChild(tool):Clone()
    clone2.Parent = player.StarterGear
end)
```

Comment: Is this a LocalScript or a server Script?

Comment: It's a LocalScript.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made in LocalScripts aren't replicated to everyone. Which means that the changes only appear for you. If you want to update your leaderstats, make the change in a Script.

To fix your problem, move the price check into the Script that is handling the ShopBuy RemoteEvent.

```
local item = script.Parent.Parent
local shopBuy = game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    shopBuy:FireServer(item)
end)
```

Then parse the details in your server Script.

```
local tools = game.ReplicatedStorage.Tools
local shopBuy = game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopBuy

shopBuy.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, item)
    -- get some details about the tool
    local toolName = item.ItemName.Value
    local price = item.Price.Value
    local money = player.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Money")

    -- check that the player has enough money
    if money.Value >= price then
        money.Value = money.Value - price

        -- give the tool
        local clone = tools:FindFirstChild(toolName):Clone()
        clone.Parent = player.Backpack

        local clone2 = tools:FindFirstChild(toolName):Clone()
        clone2.Parent = player.StarterGear
    end
end)
```

Comment: I'm not the best programmer, so I think I didn't do something correctly.

Comment: I edited the question with the script that puts the item in the inventory.

Comment: When you say, "it didn't work", did it not subtract the money properly? Did the money problem happen again? Did it not give the tool? Did it throw an error?